# Where does the extra time get consumed as shown in the profiler in my program?

Tags: python, profiler

I am using `cProfiler` for the first time in my code and trying to understand it's results.
I post here just a toy code to illustrate my problem .
There are two loops one inside the other and I don't understand which time is the profiler calculating.

So for instance, if I put the profiler outside the main loop it correctly calculates the run time of the program ( around 7 s) :

```
prof=cProfile.Profile()
tmax=100
t=0
dt=0.1
n=10000

prof.enable()
while t<tmax:
  B=[]
  t=t+dt

  for j in range(n):
    val=dt*j
    B.append(val)

  B=sorted(B)
  B=np.array(B)
  C=B*cos(dt)
  mini=min(C[C>0])
  if mini==0:
    mini=1  
prof.disable()
prof.print_stats()
```

The output:

```
 10014023 function calls in 7.323 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

       ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <ipython-input-59-761fc8d7f6eb>:22(<module>)
            1    4.316    4.316    7.322    7.322 <ipython-input-59-761fc8d7f6eb>:8(<module>)
            2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codeop.py:140(__call__)
            2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hooks.py:139(__call__)
            2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hooks.py:204(pre_run_code_hook)
            2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 interactiveshell.py:1067(user_global_ns)
            2    0.000    0.000    7.322    3.661 interactiveshell.py:2852(run_code)
            2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ipstruct.py:125(__getattr__)
            2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.compile}
            2    0.000    0.000    7.322    3.661 {built-in method builtins.exec}
         1001    0.996    0.001    0.996    0.001 {built-in method builtins.min}
         1001    0.119    0.000    0.119    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sorted}
         1001    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {built-in method math.cos}
         1001    0.982    0.001    0.982    0.001 {built-in method numpy.array}
     10010000    0.906    0.000    0.906    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
            1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Consider what happens if I put the profiler as follows:

```
    prof=cProfile.Profile()
tmax=100
t=0
dt=0.1
n=10000


while t<tmax:
  prof.enable()
  B=[]
  t=t+dt

  for j in range(n):
    val=dt*j
    B.append(val)

  B=sorted(B)
  B=np.array(B)
  C=B*cos(dt)
  mini=min(C[C>0])
  if mini==0:
    print("Zero")    
  prof.disable()
prof.print_stats()
```

Output:

```
       10015005 function calls in 3.032 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1001    1.014    0.001    1.014    0.001 {built-in method builtins.min}
     1001    0.120    0.000    0.120    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sorted}
     1001    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {built-in method math.cos}
     1001    0.963    0.001    0.963    0.001 {built-in method numpy.array}
 10010000    0.930    0.000    0.930    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1001    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

In the latter case, if the profiler is just showing the time of the last while loop iteration then it still doesn't make sense because if one iteration takes 3s then only 2 iterations would give total time of around 7s but there are a lot more iterations happening (around 1000)

So, what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the profiler does not seem to give correct answers when it is used to profile sequential code, rather than a function.

for example here the time and profiler time are very different.

```
...
s = time.time()
prof.enable()

#line1
#line2
...
#lineN

e = time.time()
prof.disable()
```

but this gives the correct result. when you put line1...lineN in a function foo()

```
...
s = time.time()
prof.enable()

foo()

e = time.time()
prof.disable()
...
```

so edit your code, and format it by putting the code you want to profile inside a function and then use the profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reported ncalls, its pretty clear that the latter case is showing the cumulative info of all 1001 iterations of the while loop  (Its 1001 and not 1000 due to the floating point imprecision of t += 0.1)

The difference in the former vs the latter is clearly the 4+ seconds the former example spent processing the action `<ipython-input-59-761fc8d7f6eb>:8(<module>)`

It looks like you're running these tests in an interpreter.  Have you tried running the same code as a script instead?